# Updatepanel not working with button click

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I have a updatepanel when i click on the button I am not entering the method.What am I doing wrong I have search a lot and tried a lot of different updatemodes but know are working.

Here is my front end code

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
</asp:ScriptManager>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
            <ContentTemplate>                
     <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Periodo de tiempo" CssClass="second-menu-title"></asp:Label>

         <div class="form-row">
             <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
            <label for="validationCountry">Año</label><br/>
                                <asp:DropDownList class="form-control" ID="drYear" runat="server"  ></asp:DropDownList>
             </div>
         <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
            <label for="validationCountry">Mes</label><br/>
                              <asp:DropDownList class="form-control"  ID="drMonth" runat="server" ></asp:DropDownList>                     
             </div>
      </div>                             

             <asp:Button class="btn btn-primary" ID="btnTimeInterval" Enabled="True" runat="server" Text="Cambiar meses"  onclick="selectedTimeIntervalClick"/>  
                  <br/>
                </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnTimeInterval" />
            </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Here is my backend code

```
    protected void selectedTimeIntervalClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            string year = drYear.SelectedValue;
            string month = drMonth.SelectedValue;

            PopulateDateDropDownsAndSearchBoxes();

            string selectContract = year.Substring(year.Length - 2) + month;

            PopulateDefaultDates();
            PopulateSearch();

    }
```

Comment: Check browser developer console (press F12) for any javascript errors.

Comment: Did you add the script manager?  Can you provide the full page HTML?  What is selectedTimeIntervalClick

Comment: Yes I have a script manager. I will add it to my question